# SQL query for import data

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, import, excel

How can I write a single line SQL for importing 20k rows data from Excel to  SQL server ? 
Please don't tell me about import export wizard or to write 20 line repeatedly for do the same.

Please tell me if you have any other method.

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen the Microsoft Support article [How to import data from Excel to SQL Server](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/321686/how-to-import-data-from-excel-to-sql-server)?

They document a variety of ways to do it.  Specifically the section of "Use Distributed Queries" seems like what you're asking:

> If you do not want to configure a persistent connection to the Excel workbook as a linked server, you can import data for a specific purpose by using the `OPENDATASOURCE` or the `OPENROWSET` function. The following code samples also import the data from the Excel Customers worksheet into new SQL Server tables:
>
> ```
> SELECT * INTO XLImport3 FROM OPENDATASOURCE('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0',
> 'Data Source=C:\test\xltest.xls;Extended Properties=Excel 8.0')...[Customers$]
>
> SELECT * INTO XLImport4 FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0',
> 'Excel 8.0;Database=C:\test\xltest.xls', [Customers$])
>
> SELECT * INTO XLImport5 FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0',
> 'Excel 8.0;Database=C:\test\xltest.xls', 'SELECT * FROM [Customers$]')
> ```

See also [OPENROWSET and linked servers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/import-data-from-excel-to-sql?view=sql-server-2017#openrowset) in the product documentation.